# Discrete Convolution of unit step functions

Tags: convolution

convolution of the following functions?

> (u[n] - u[n-5]) * (u[n] - u[n-5])

In order to solve it I said:

> u[n] - u[n-5] = δ[n] + δ[n-1] + δ[n-2] + δ[n-3] + δ[n-4]

and the answer is

> δ[n] + 2δ[n-1]+ 3 δ[n-2] + 4δ[n-3] + 5δ[n-4] + 4δ[n-5] + 3δ[n-6] + 2δ[n-7] + δ[n-8]

but I was wondering is there a way to use the convolutional sum with the unit step functions
instead of impulses?

Comment: Hi @System. Welcome! You might find this [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful :)